# Конвертация массива string в массив int

Tags: c#

Как можно конвертировать строку чисел, разделённых пробелом, в массив int?

```
int[] arr = new int[20];
int countThree = 0;
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    arr[i] = rnd.Next(-10000, 10000);
    Console.WriteLine($"{arr[i]}");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно с помощью метода [String.Split](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = "23 -123 -400 453 900";
            int[] values = text.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(int.Parse)
                .ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(values[i].ToString());
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Или так, если всё-таки нужен один проход по значениям, то можно и не конвертировать в массив, а пройтись итератором:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = "23 -123 -400 453 900";
            var values = text.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(int.Parse);

            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Как можно конвертировать строку чисел, разделённых пробелом, в массив int?

Код не проверял, могут быть мелкие ошибки.

```
string strWithInts= "1 2 3 4 5";

var intsArr = strWithInts.Split().Select(int32.Parse).ToArray();
```

Comment: `.Split()` по умолчанию разбивает [по пробелу](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,1195), указание в данном случае лишнее. Также лямбда у `.Select()` тоже лишняя в данном примере. достаточно просто `.Select(int.Parse)`.